# Dynamically generating closures based in input for search (Laravel / Elequent)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'd like to generate an query like this:

```
select * from `recipes` 
                  where ((`menu` LIKE '%dinner%' or `menu` LIKE '%lunch%') 
                  and (`type` LIKE '%steak%' or `soort` LIKE '%chicken%'))
                  order by RAND() asc limit 1
```

While my input looks like this:

`"menu1" => "dinner"
 "menu2" => "lunch"
 "type1" => "steak"
 "type2" => "chicken"`

This is how my code looks right now **PHP**:

```
  foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
            $key = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $key);
            if($oldKey == $key){
                $andOr = 'OR';
            } else {
                $andOr = 'AND';
            }

                if($oldKey == $key)
                {
                    $query->where(function($query) use ($key, $value){
                       $query->where($key, "LIKE", "%$value%");
                    });
                } else {
                    $query->orWhere(function($query) use ($key, $value)
                    {
                        $query->orWhere($key, "LIKE", "%$value%");
                    });
                }

            }

            $oldKey = $key;
    });

    $recipe = $query->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->limit(1)->get();
```

but sadly this generating something like this:

```
select * from `recipes` 
                      where ((`menu` LIKE '%dinner%') 
                       or (`menu` LIKE '%lunch%') 
                       or (`type` LIKE '%steak%') 
                       or (`type` LIKE '%chicken%')) 
                order by RAND() asc limit 1
```

Which isn't correct.

I'm trying to make this piece of code dynamic so i can give it more or less input variables and still generates a "valid" query. With valid i mean the parentheses are placed like in the first query.

I hope i made everything clear and thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your inputs formats to

`"menu" => ["dinner", "lunch" ]
"type" => ["steak", "chicken"]`

You can do it using this approach.

`<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="dinner">`

And now, will much more easy to manager that data on your code.

```
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    $query->where(function($query) use ($key, $value){
        foreach($value as $item) {
            $query->orWhere($key, "LIKE", "%{$item}%");
        }
    });
}

$recipe = $query->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->limit(1)->get();
```

I didn't test it, but this is the path you should follow.